# getting 'ObsoleteTrait' when adding a trait in a testCase

Tags: oop, smalltalk, traits, pharo, testcase

I'm having a problem.

I'm using a code in a testCase
It starts like this

```
|mapeos obj myClass|

myClass := Smalltalk at: #ClaseForTesting.

myClass addToComposition: TraitPruebaCondicion1.
```

the   `#ClaseForTesting` is an emptyClass

when smalltalk do

```
myClass addToComposition: TraitPruebaCondicion1
```

if I (Debugging) try to get the traits

```
myClass traits
```

I'm getting

```
an OrderedCollection(AnObsoleteTraitPruebaCondicion1)
```

why is adding `AnObsolete` in the string trait name?
If I run the same code in workspace, it works really fine.

Why is this happening? any ideas?
Please, its urgent :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't believe that I was stuck with this a lot of time, and then when I FINALLY decided to ask to the people, I've solve it in two minutes. Shame on me. It must be some kind of mystical brainstorming with this site.

Anyway, the clue was to using

```
Smalltalk at: #
```

with the trait too! (I was only using it on the class)

so

```
myClass addToComposition:(Smalltalk at: #TraitPruebaCondicion1).
```

solve my problem.